# How can I configure my server to avoid information leakage from the SERVER header of its HTTP response

Tags: security, apache-httpd, php, openssl

I have a centos 7 server with apache v2.4.6 php 5.4.16 and OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips installed. I was just doing a scan to it to see how secure my server is. I found out that my server is giving out information about what versions of apache, ssl and php I have, which I don't like it that much. Is there any way to configure my server to avoid giving this information?

Comment: Are you sure that not giving this information would really increase a lot the overall security (I believe that not). But you certainly should be able to configure Apache (or recompile it - it is free software) to suite your needs

Comment: Yes, you are right. Is not going to increase a lot of overall security. But at least if there are any problems with a version I have installed I don't want to give out this information which is not necessary for a normal user to know.

Comment: Then dive into Apache documentation (or its source code). You could also use some other web server, e.g. [lighttpd](http://lighttpd.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, at least in part, governed by the [ServerTokens directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens), so you could set

```
ServerTokens Prod
```

which will reveal only that the Server is an unspecified version of Apache, but even the manual itself suggests this is not a security measure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, are there any other things to do so it doesn't show PHP and SSL version?

Comment: Is it true that these no longer work? Somebody here http://www.petefreitag.com/item/419.cfm said this:  I added both into the httpd.conf on Debian Squeeze and OpenVAS reported: 
Apache Web Server version 2.2.16 was detected on the host.

Comment: I can't speak to Debian, but on CentOS 7, going from the default (no setting) to `ServerTokens Prod` changes the header from `Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)` to `Server: Apache`, as expected. Sometimes people (me included) think something doesn't work because they can't get it to work.

Comment: Thank you @Ulrich Schwarz for your answer, I will see tomorrow if that worked. Do you know by any chance how can I do it for SSL and PHP?